# How to get number of channels from mp3

Tags: go, mp3

The problem does not seem to be difficult, but I spent a lot of time, tried several libraries and did not find a solution.
for example github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3 dosen't contain necessary func.

```
    file, err := os.Open("example.mp3")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    decoder, err := mp3.NewDecoder(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer decoder.Close()

    sampleRate := decoder.SampleRate()
    numChannels := ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3` knows the the number of channels. It's just not exported. See [the implementation](https://github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3/blob/fa70610237c8c313ef920c7cff6c31efbbc55ffa/internal/frameheader/frameheader.go#L218-L223).

The bad news is that the package was archived on Apr 3, 2023. But it should be easy to fork the repository and modify the code according to your need.

I have tried to fork the repository and export `(*Decoder).NumberOfChannels`. See this [commit](https://github.com/ZekeLu/go-mp3/commit/a7ed31bb577833a491b2f0cd1df087e290f19a24). And here is the demo to use the forked version of the package (with the [replace directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace)):

**Note**: I'm not sure what do you expect from the number of channels. But `(*Decoder).NumberOfChannels` always returns *1* (`mono` mode) or *2* (`stereo` mode). [This doc](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm) mentions that MPEG-2/Multichannel has up to 5 full range audio channels and an LFE-channel. But the "MPEG Audio Frame Header" section in that doc does not provide any information about it.

**go.mod**

```
module example.com/m

go 1.20

replace github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3 v0.3.4 => github.com/ZekeLu/go-mp3 v0.3.5-pre

require github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3 v0.3.4
```

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("classic.mp3")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    decoder, err := mp3.NewDecoder(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("channels:", decoder.NumberOfChannels())
}
```