# error in importing forked golang driver in application to connect to database

Tags: go, import, module, driver

I have forked an open-source golang driver and made some changes. Now I am facing an issue while importing it on my application using the command --> go get "path to my go driver on my personal github account". What is the exact procedure, can anyone suggest?

I am expecting the exact steps to import the driver on my personal account.

Comment: Use the `replace` directive. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76070432/1369400

Comment: Tried, but my application is not able to detect. Could you please give me an example to import local package(it is a driver) in go application.

Comment: To replace a module with the one in your local machine, use the `replace` directive like this: `replace module_path => /path/to/local/file/path/to/the/replacement/module/root/directory`. See https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace

Comment: now it is going through the package files but in between it is failing because there is some dependency, if I download the dependency, then it is saying that the driver imported but not used, so the issue is with the internal dependency in the driver.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducer.

Comment: so actually I tried to import the package locally( I copied it in GoRoot path and my application was able to access the package but, there was a file inside that package which imports the sub-package from same ealier package which I tried to import locally, so what I can do now, it is unable to identify that inner package folder even though the parent package folder has been identified by the go application.

Comment: what to do if a package is locally imported and  there is sub-package inside the package which is imported remotely, how to handle this situation. So basically the parent package is same.